# Problems for which scala/akka or go are a better fit

Tags: scala, go, akka

In looking into Go recently it seems like one could analogize between Go and Scala/Akka, 
where an akka Actor is similar to a goroutine and an ActorRef is similar to a Go channel.

Other than platform type issues (JVM or not) what are the functional differences that would lead one to choose one or the other?

Answer (score 10):

Disclaimer: I am the product owner of Akka

You could probably implement the Actor Model on top of goroutines and channels,
but I see them as two distinctly different layers of abstraction.

Questions for the person choosing could be virtually anything but here are some suggestions:

1. Dev/Deployment platform?
2. Possibility/desire to reuse other libraries and/or languages?
3. Remoting/Clustering?
4. Development environment/infrastructure
5. Availability of developers
6. ...

If someone knows if there is an Actor Model impl for Golang I'd love a linky.

Answer (score -3):

I feel like Scala / Akka is more mature. There is a bigger use community, and more momentum.

Other people won't agree, but to me Go still feels like a "me too", and I would not code anything serious in a "me too" language.